# What for is equals sign after a type in specialization struct?

Tags: c++, templates, specifications

I faced such a code:

```
template <int = 42>
struct Foo{
int x;   };
```

Does it have sense, or it's complete nonsense?

Comment: `int = 42` declares an unnamed non-type template parameter with default value `42`. (Same as function parameters.)

Comment: fwiw, it isnt complete nonsense. `Foo` might be used as tag, and then all you want from the template parameter is that `Foo<1>` is a different type than `Foo<2>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equal to

```
template <int I = 42>
struct Foo {
  int x;
}
```

so a **non-type template parameter of type `int` that is defaulted to `42`** but as nobody is using `I`, it does not have any effect on the contents of the `struct`.

When declaring `Foo` as

```
Foo foo {};
```

this will result in `Foo<T>` being `Foo<42>` but one could also declare

```
Foo<1> foo {};
```

or similar which would be a different instantiation of the `template struct`. If that makes sense really depends on your code but it is **valid C++ syntax**.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yeah, sure, correct. Thanks for noticing!